# Finding the memory of each BLOB

Tags: c#, azure, azure-blob-storage

that I've used for these 5 blobs? (note that the number could change from 5 to 10 to 13, to anything)

Here's what I've got so far:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {  
        CloudBlockBlob blob = 
            sampleContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("APictureFile.jpg");
    }
}
```

My questions:

Comment: Question looks to be incomplete and should be fixed as it was previously answered and it's not clear *what* the question actually was.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this (if I'm correct in assuming you're looking for the cumulative length of files)

```
var blobs = sampleContainer.ListBlobs();
int size = 0;

foreach(var blobItem in blobs) {
  CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)blobItem ;
  blob.FetchAttributes();
  size+= blob.Properties.Length;
}
```

Comment: Any idea why it's not letting me use .FetchAttributes and .Properties? I have using Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.Blob;

Comment: I don't have access to an IDE but you may need to cast the blobItem to a CloudBlockBlob before calling the methods. I'll update my answer.